# Is there a visual CMake tool?

Tags: cmake, editor, cmake-gui

I'm loking for a purely visual (not a code editor) tool for editing CMake files (i.e., `CMakeLists.txt`). If you know one, please post here, thanks.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here.  But I'd be interested to know what a purely visual tool for editing a text file is.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark how is it off-topic?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ - [Quoting straight from the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: CMakeLists:s are text files, or rather they are programs written in the CMake programming language. There is no way to represent them as something graphical so that you could drag things around... There are good editing modes for Emacs and Visual Studio, though.

Comment: CMake is so well documented, and so easy that I can not understand how a visual editor could help !!!?? emacs is enough....and does the trick ....

Comment: @sancelot C++ is so well-documented, why to use code editor or IDE, let's write code in Notepad. Hint: programming language and code editor are different entitties

Answer (score 4):

No there is not. However you can have a look at [CMake Tools for Visual Studio](http://cmaketools.codeplex.com/)

> Features include the following:
>
> - Syntax highlighting for CMake code
> - Member selection list boxes for CMake commands and variables
> - Tool tips giving the parameters to CMake commands
> - Brace matching for CMake code
> - Support for CMake code snippets
> - Context-sensitive help, available by pressing F1 in the Visual Studio    editor while the insertion point is over a standard CMake
>     command or    variable
> - Access to the CMake GUI and documentation from the Tools menu in    Visual Studio

Comment: Doesn't really help since I don't want to be editing text files by hand